# defaultdict(list) creates a new key for every element of torch tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pytorch, torch

Can someone explain me how I can solve this problem: for example, I have torch tensor [1, 1]. Why when I want do something like that:

```
b = defaultdict(list)
b[torch.tensor(1)].append(2)
b[torch.tensor(1)].append(3)
```

I got two new keys and two elements of defaultdict: (1: 2), (1: 3) but I wanted to do (1: 2, 3). How I can fix it? Thank you in advance

Comment: it seems like torch Tensor objects hash by id: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/dcec2100b1e7a8627d86fed84a0fa36725e4453a/torch/_tensor.py#L943 So I doubt this will be useful for whatever you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new tensor each time.

```
k = torch.tensor(1)
b[k].append(2)
b[k].append(3)
```

Comment: but if I have torch tensor [1, 1, 1]?

Comment: I mean I have something like torch.tensor and each element of this tensor is tuple if two torch tensors like `a = torch.tensor[(torch.tensor, torch.tensor(int))]` and I want to do like that:  `b = defaultdict(list)`, `b[a[1]].append(a[0]) `

Comment: @randomuser228 what if you do? (why dont you try it... or maybe you did and got an error, in which case you should tell us the error) generally tuples are fine as keys to dictionaries...

Comment: I don't use Torch, can you extract the tuple from it instead of using the tensor itself as the key? That should solve the problem, too. @randomuser228

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in comments, tensor objects are hashed by id, so every time you create new tensor, you will have new id.
To see this,

```
for key, val in b.items():
  print(key, hash(key), id(key))
# output: 
# tensor(1) 140513660621744 140513660621744
# tensor(1) 140513650260544 140513650260544
```

Note you will have different id than mine. So either define it one time as @Barmar suggested, or if it's one item tensor, just call `.item()` method.